# Why is my recursion sudoku solver not working?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sudoku

I wrote this function to solve sudoku grids.
The possible value function works properly, by returning a set of all possible values for the Cell and I just can't find out why I keep getting TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable.

```
class SudokuSolver(Sudoku):
    def __init__(self, grid):
        self.grid = grid

def numbers_from_row(self, row):
    """valid numbers for row"""
    row_num = set()
    valid_num = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
    for i in range(9):
        row_num.add(self.grid[row][i])
    for num in row_num:
        if num in valid_num:
            valid_num.remove(num)
    return valid_num

def numbers_from_column(self, column):
    """valid numbers for column"""
    col_num = set()
    valid_num = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
    for i in range(9):
        col_num.add(self.grid[i][column])
    for num in col_num:
        if num in valid_num:
            valid_num.remove(num)
    return valid_num

def numbers_from_box(self, row, column):
    """valid numbers for box"""
    box_num = set()
    valid_num = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
    for i in range(0, 3):
        for j in range(0, 3):
            box_num.add(self.grid[((row // 3) * 3) + i][((column // 3) * 3) + j])
    for num in box_num:
        if num in valid_num:
            valid_num.remove(num)
    return valid_num

def possible_values(self, row, column):
    """all possible values"""
    return self.numbers_from_row(row).intersection(self.numbers_from_column(column), self.numbers_from_box(row, column))

def solve(self):
    for i in range(9):
        for j in range(9):
            if self.grid[i][j] == 0:
                for num in self.possible_values(i, j):
                    self.grid[i][j] = num
                    self.solve()
                    self.grid[i][j] = 0
                return 
    return self.grid
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: That's not just a function it's a method, please show the class definition as well.

Comment: `self.grid` appears to be `None`, or to contain `None`s - the code that initializes it is where you should be looking for the problem.  But note that the code you posted wouldn't actually work anyway - since you undo each possible move after making the recursive call, the `return` at the end will just give you the original state of the grid.

Comment: just added the whole class

Comment: If you are not getting an error, it could be that your recursive approach is just taking too long.